# Rails does not recognize model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method on my model and it actually was created as advised(with self.method_name). However, when I go to my console and try to test the method I get an `undefined method` error.
Does anyone know why?

**my Model**

```
  class Country < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :facts
    has_many :dishes
    has_many :touristic_places
    include HTTParty
    base_uri 'restcountries.eu/rest/v2/region/africa'

    def self.save_data_from_api
        response = HTTParty.get(base_uri)
        country_data = JSON.parse(response)
        countries = country_data.map do |line|
            c = Country.new
            c.name = line.name
            c.save
            c
        end
        countries.select(&:persisted?)
    end
```

**On my Controller**

```rb
  def save_data_from_api
    countrie = Country.save_data_from_api
  end
```

**Test on Rails console error:**

```
> Country.save_data_from_api
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):5
        1: from (irb):5:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NoMethodError (undefined method `save_data_from_api' for #<Class:0x00007fc9ec71edd8>)
```

Comment: Add more information with model and controller code, and also with console error backtrace.

Comment: I have added the actual code

Comment: "when I go to my console "  > can yo please also add to cod you used on the console (assuming rails console here)

Comment: Can you please do the following in the rails console: `Country.methods` and verify if it is there? also please do a `reload!` ?

Comment: I ran the command to see all the methods and basically I only saw the reserved methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do HTTP calls in your model. Even without any code your model already has a ton of responsibilities that it gets from `ActiveRecord::Base`:

- validations
- assocations
- persistence
- callbacks
- naming
- i18n

Instead create a separate client object that fetches the data from the API. This gives you an object which just does one job which is both easy to test and stub out:

```
# app/clients/rest_countries_client.rb
# HTTP client for the restcountries.eu API
class RestCountriesClient 
  include HTTParty

  base_uri 'restcountries.eu/rest/v2'
  format :json # this will automatically parse the response

  def self.region(region)
     get("/region/#{region}")
  end
end
```

This lets you just test the API call from the console by calling `RestCountriesClient.region('africa')` and you can see the returned hash without any side-effects.

To actually do the call and persist the objects you want to use a service object or [ActiveJob](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html):

```
# app/jobs/country_importer_job.rb
# Persists countries from the restcountries.eu API
class CountryImporterJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(region = 'africa')
    response = RestCountriesClient.region(region)
    return unless response.success?
    response.map do |line|
      Country.create(name: line["name"])
    end.select(&:persisted?)
  end
end
```

You would then call this job from the controller:

```
CountryImporterJob.perform_now('africa')
```

Comment: I tested the client file and it gives me this error NameError (uninitialized constant RestCountriesClient)

Comment: def import_countries
          countries_imported = CountryImporterJob.perform_now('africa')
        end

Comment: That's how I imported the job (tell if is wrong) and it also gives me an error "NoMethodError (undefined method `import_countries' for #<Class:0x0000559340b10ca0>)"

Comment: You may need run `spring stop` and start `rails c` again. The autoloader tends to have problems picking up new directories.

Comment: I keep having the same problems. Should I try to create a route and see the results on Postman or browser?

Comment: Are you still getting the  uninitialized constant error? Did you ensure that you that file names and paths are correct? I made a few minor typos and forgot to set the job to inherit from ApplicationJob. Edited.

Comment: yea everything looks the same but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? I tried this code in Rails 6 and it does work as advertised https://gist.github.com/maxcal/0a4630eed5459a8cdde2bc20017c067d

Comment: Rails 6, I'm not really getting it tho

Comment: I was reading the Job docs, do I need to configure the queues ?

Comment: Not if you are using `.perform_now`. The job is run immediately and never qued. Here is an example app https://github.com/maxcal/countries_app

Comment: I'm so sorry for the delay, I'm checking now your repo

Comment: Either that or just a browser

Answer (score 0):

Quit the console and start it again. Auto-reload only works in the server, not the console.

Comment: I keep having the same problems. Should I try to create a route and see the results on Postman or browser?